# 301 редирект со и без слеша на одну страницу

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Нужно сделать редирект старых страниц, или же их объединить.
Код ниже не срабатывает:

```
Redirect 301 /category/roboty-pylesosy-irobot /category/roboty-pylesosy/irobot/?
Redirect 301 /category/roboty-pylesosy-irobot/ /category/roboty-pylesosy/irobot/?
```

Comment: А знак вопроса в конце для чего?

Comment: Только с ним срабатывает коректно, возможно нюансы сервера

Comment: Тогда совсем ничего не понятно. Вы пишите `Код ниже не срабатывает`. И следом: `Только с ним срабатывает коректно`. Так по итогу срабатывает или нет? Знак вопроса в GET запросе означает, что последует передача параметров, например:  `/irobot/?foo=bar&foo2=bar2`. Другие нюансы мне не известны.

Comment: @de_frag: 1) при объединении 2-х редиректов они не коректно срабатывают, по отдельности работают без ошибок; 2) "Только с ним срабатывает коректно" - относится к комментарию выше, что с знаком ? один редирект работает отлично, без ? не работает.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить две строки Redirect-а одной: `RedirectMatch 301 "/category/roboty-pylesosy-irobot/?" /category/roboty-pylesosy/irobot/?`. Мое мнение - редиректы объединить нельзя, т.к. это самостоятельные независимые процессы (но здесь больше вопрос терминологии и ее толкования). И не тестируйте на редиректах со статусом 301 - они кэшируются браузерами и в результате получаются всякие "чудеса".

Comment: Сработало, напишите "RedirectMatch 301 "/category/roboty-pylesosy-irobot/?" /category/roboty-pylesosy/irobot/?" здесь как отдельный ответ и я выбору его как лучший.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените обе строки Redirect-а одной:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "/category/roboty-pylesosy-irobot/?" /category/roboty-pylesosy/irobot/?
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!